# Convert from curl python Request Error error 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

Im having trouble converting the curl request into a python code request.

Working Curl request

> curl -X POST "http://xxxxxx" -H "accept: application/json" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:
>   Token 882a6ec053ff6dbac623eff400f67c0bb6ade399" -d "name=namename"

Not working python request

```
headers = {
    'Authorization ': 'Token ' + "token",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data= {'name': "name"}
r = requests.post(
    host_scheme + "://" + host_netloc + "/xxxxx",
    data=json.dumps(data),
    headers=headers
)
```

The response of the error is it cannot read the token {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."} when using the python code above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope its just a sample

Comment: also tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded but same results

Comment: Where is your authorization method or key in the python code?  Your first dict key will resolve to a value of `Token token` which I suspect is not a valid authorization token.  Did you intend to say: `Authorization ': 'Token ' + token` and `token` is defined somewhere above and not shown in the code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
requests.post("http://xxxxxx",
    data='name=namename',
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Token 882a6ec053ff6dbac623eff400f67c0bb6ade399",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "accept": "application/json"
    },
    cookies={},
)
```

I used [Uncurl](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl). I had to remove the `-X POST`.